# How to get DetailsList/Selection component on React Fabric UI to work with ReactHooks?

Tags: react-hooks, office-ui-fabric

I'm having issue getting the React Fabric UI DetailsList to work with React Hooks.  It renders, but the selection part does not.  Whenever, you select a row, I expect the count of the selection to be updated.  However, i'm not seeing that.  It looks like the selection component items never get updated even thou the UI shows it being selected.  I'm also seeing the onSelectionChange being triggered when you select a row.  Now sure if its because i'm using react hooks or what

I took the provided class example which works:

`[Codepen]https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true (Example)`

Same as the original but stripped down

`[Codepen]https://codepen.io/darewreckk/pen/NQRWEd?editors=1111`

converted it to a react hook component.  I would expect the same thing, but i'm not and can't figure out what's different.

Modified Example with Hooks

`[Codepen]https://codepen.io/darewreckk/pen/GVjRNb?editors=1111`

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

The selection count is stored on the `Selection` object that you are creating. You could log it out like so:

```
  const _selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: () => { 
        console.log('Selected count:' + _selection.count);
      }
  });
```

You can set the value of `selectionCount` and `selectionDetails` whenever `onSelectionChanged` is called:

```
  const _selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: () => { 
        setSelectionCount(_selection.count);
        setSelectionDetails(`${_selection.count} items selected`)
      }
  });
```

---

As a side note: If you want `selectionDetails` to update when `selectionCount` updates, you can use the `useEffect` hook:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSelectionDetails(`${selectionCount} items selected`);
  }, [selectionCount]);
```

The above effect will run whenever `selectionCount` updates, and so in turn update `selectionDetails`.

Comment: I looked at that codepen. I think the Selection object is being created on each render. I'm finding that the problem becomes more complicated in hooks when you preserve the Selection object. It seems very difficult to add the callback in the Selection constructor when you are placing the Selection object into a safe location. Using EventnGroup helps though and seems to be the only way to get a selection change notification if not using the constructor.

Comment: @user1763729, thanks for pointing that out. I was just modifying the sample code from the docs. In the new code sample above, I've changed it to use `useMemo` for the Selection object.

Comment: @mtl can you update you answer code according to the comment mentioned above and also link is no longer working. thanks